# Flex DropDownList dropDown displayObject is stays visible

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu

My dropDownList dropDown displayObject is stays visible after I am selecting an option.

This is my source:

```
public function myList_changeHandler(event:Event){
   myList.selectedItem = -1;
   isVisible = false
}

<s:HGroup visible="{isVisible}">
    <s:DropDownList  id="myList" dataProvider="{data}" change="myList_changeHandler(event)"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

This bug have something with `isVisible` property but I just don't know what I can do.

How can I make the dropDown displayObject to disappear(removeChild and set viability false not working, it disappears for good...)?

Comment: seems like can you post your entire code, because i just added a dropdown list and it works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by resting the `dataProvider`, setting it to null and back to it's original value

Answer (score 0):

The drop down of the DropDownList is placed using the PopUpManager; so it's parent is not formally the DropDownList nor the HGroup.  Thus I would not expect the HGroup visibility to make the drop down disappear.

You can try something like this:

```
PopUpManager.removePopUp(myList.dropDown as IFlexDisplayObject);
```

in your change handler method.

Comment: Not working, it removes the view, but then the dropDownList is not working anymore, same as when I am playing with viability.

Comment: @Babibu How about calling myList.close() in the change handler?

Answer (score 0):

did u set isVisible as a Bindable... if not then it won't work
make it as Bindable

```
[Bindable] private var isVisible:Boolean;
```

try this and check the change handler is properly calling or not....